# Sql where on a computed column count()

Tags: sql, count, where-clause

I am attempting to perform a search of how many times a user has logged into the system.

There's a table that tracks ip, user and login time.

I am attempting a simple query like:

```
select COUNT(*) as loginCount, ip, email from login_attempts where (loginCount LIKE '%1%') group by `email`
```

But this leads to an error unknown column 'loginCount', how should this be done then if I want to search a column that was computed in the select?

Comment: count is an integer method . why you use the like command ???!!!!

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select COUNT(*) as loginCount, ip, email from login_attempts
  group by ip, email
```

or if you are interested only in email

```
  select COUNT(*) as loginCount,email from login_attempts
  group by  email
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `HAVING`

```
select COUNT(*) as loginCount, ip, email 
from login_attempts 
group by ip, `email`
having COUNT(*) LIKE '%1%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This logic:

```
loginCount LIKE '%1%'
```

Makes little sense for a *number*.  Do you really want counts with values like `1`, `11`, `21`, `134189` but not `2` or `2343`?  That is, that only contain the digit `1` in the count?

Even if the logic made sense, it is in the wrong place, because you need to filter *after* aggregation.  And, your aggregation is inconsistent with the `select` columns -- `ip` is not an aggregation key so drop it from the `select`.

Your specific logic would be more appropriately written as:

```
select count(*) as loginCount, email
from login_attempts
group by email
having cast(count(*) as varchar(255)) LIKE '%1%';
```

That seems silly.  I imagine you want something like users that have one login attempt.  That would be:

```
select count(*) as loginCount, email
from login_attempts
group by email
having count(*) = 1;
```